# After switching Views, I want my label text to remain what it was before switching

Tags: uilabel

I am really close with this. And I apologize for being so new at coding. This question is probably not the hardest thing to figure out. Here are some things you should know beforehand:

Right now I have a simple tally app for a IRL board game I'm making.

The tally app itself is not on the main View of the app. So, to get to the tally app, I click a button.

On the tally app theres an up and down button for +1 and -1.

There's a UILabel that shows this result. So when I press the up button 3 times, the label on the app says "3".

But when I go back to the main view, and then go back to the tally app, the number is still there, but it shows as "0". When I press the up button, it says "4". Not "1". So it KNOWS the state of the label, but it doesn't SHOW the state of the label. It shows 0 when I go back and forth between views.

How can I make it show the state of the label when switching views and coming back?

Here is my `viewDidLoad` code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    Count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", Number];   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the same code in "`viewDidAppear`" as well. viewDidLoad is called only once when the view is created, not every time it appears.

In viewDidLoad, make sure to call `[super viewDidLoad];` in be beginning. Do the similar in viewDidAppear.

Comment: Do I put [super viewDidLoad]; in the brackets inside of viewDidLoad? Because when I do that, it says "UIView may not respond to viewDidLoad"

Comment: Here is my code:
`
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
Count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", Number];
}




- (void)viewDidAppear
{
    [super viewDidAppear];
    Count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", Number];
}`

Comment: I assumed you were doing this in the View Controller. Are you doing this in a UIView subclass?

Comment: I'm not sure :(

This code is in my ViewController.m .. and at the top of my ViewController.m it says `@implementation ViewController` ... at the top of my ViewController.h it says `@interface ViewController : UIView`

Comment: ViewController's superclass should be UIViewController and not UIView. Make the following change:`@interface ViewController: UIViewController`